# How to center text inside a TWebMemo component

Tags: delphi, center, tms, tms-web-core

I am attempting to center my text within my TWebMemo component however I am unable to do it, does anyone perhaps know how to center the text?

Comment: It is not clear which memo component you use. Standard Delphi TMemo component has nothing to format text in any way. It is just like Windows Notepad application : raw text. Use TRichEdit instead. This is a RTF component which is able to format text like Windows WordPad application.

Comment: Forgot to say that you can add spaces in front of each line to center it. You can get the memo width, the fontsize and text width (See TCanvas property) and compute how many spaces you have to insert.

Comment: Thanks for your edit. Still, you did not clarify, whether you ask for centering horizontally, vertically or both

Comment: TMemo _does_ have a property for horizontal alignment of the text, though. It's the Alignment property, with values taLeftJustify, taCenter, taRightJustify.

Comment: I see that the original question has been edited and now asks about TWebMemo instead of TMemo. I don't know if also TWebMemo has an Alignment property or not.

Comment: @tombrunberg I would like to center it both horizontally as well as vertically

Answer (score 1):

Set the TMemo's Alignment property to taCenter instead of taLeftJustify.

Comment: I see that the original question has been edited and now says TWebMemo instead of TMemo. I don't know if my answer still applies to a TWebMemo. It applied to a standard TMemo.

Comment: I checked just now. The `TWebMemo` doesn't have an `Alignment` property.

Answer (score 1):

Vertically centering the text in a `TWebMemo` is a bit tricky, but here's an answer to horizontally align the text in the `TWebMemo`. There isn't an `Alignment` property like there is with the VCL `TMemo` component.

You have two ways to horizontally align the text. One with Bootstrap and one without Bootstrap.

## Without Bootstrap

The `TWebMemo` is actually just a normal HTML `<textarea>` tag when it's compiled to HTML. So you can simply change the `text-align` to center the text horizontally:

```
WebMemo.ElementHandle.style.setProperty('text-align','center');
```

## With Bootstrap

If you're using Bootstrap, then you can add the `text-center` class to your `TWebMemo`'s `ElementClassName` property. You can also add this via code:

```
WebMemo.ElementClassName := 'text-center';
```

If you already have other Bootstrap classes on it, then you can do the following to just add your new class with the existing classes:

```
WebMemo.ElementClassName := WebMemo.ElementClassName + ' text-center';
```